# How to use common API for dispatching multiple action creators in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 2 objects in my state and I call a common API for getting data by passing the `id` in the request.

Following is my `fetch` call for the first Section which fires receiveSectionA to update sectionA in my state.

```
export function fetchSection(sectionCode){
  return(dispatch,getState,api)=>{
    const endPoint = 'url/?sectionCode='+sectionCode
    const  method = 'GET'
    const isAuth = true
    const promise = api(endPoint,method,isAuth)
    promise
    .then(response =>
      response.json().then(json => ({
        status:response.status ,
        json
      })
    ))
    .then(
      ({ status, json }) => {
        if( status >= 200 && status < 300) {
          const sectionDictionary = utils.convertSectionsToDictionary(camelizeKeys(json))
          dispatch(receiveSectionA(sectionDictionary))
        }
        if (status >= 400 ) {
          //throw error
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log("error"+err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now I making a same call for sectionB which fires following :-

```
dispatch(receiveSectionB(sectionDictionary))
```

Now since the above `fetch` call is same is there any way I can make this generic. I feel there is too much of code repeat.

I was thinking about switch cases to dispatch different actions based on sectionCode but I have around 20 sections and I think the code will get really complicated.

Is there a better to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are looking for a `dynamic function call`. You can use `eval` which may lead to unexpected result. So, use with caution.

Expecting you have two function as `receiveSectionA` and `receiveSectionB`;

```
export function fetchSection(sectionCode){
  return(dispatch,getState,api)=>{
     ....................
    ))
    .then(
      ({ status, json }) => {
        if( status >= 200 && status < 300) {

          const sectionDictionary = utils.convertSectionsToDictionary(camelizeKeys(json))
          let funToCall = 'receiveSection' + sectionCode + '(sectionDictionary )'; // preparing function to call
          dispatch(eval(funToCall)); // Calling Function
        }
        if (status >= 400 ) {
          //throw error
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log("error"+err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:
Read more about `eval` especially the `Security` Section-
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Comment: this looks interesting. But what do you mean by unexpected results?

Comment: answer updated with links.. Read, Learn, Forget... :D

Answer (score 0):

After pondering over this a bit, clearly `eval` is not a good option.

I thought I would try one of the amazing things that Javascript supports which is passing functions as parameters.

While dispatching an action I pass the receiveActionCreator as callback.

so my `fetch` would now be:-

```
export function fetchSection(callback,sectionCode){
  return(dispatch,getState,api)=>{
     ....................
    ))
    .then(
      ({ status, json }) => {
        if( status >= 200 && status < 300) {

          const sectionDictionary = utils.convertSectionsToDictionary(camelizeKeys(json))

          dispatch(callback(sectionDictionary)); // Calling Function
        }
        if (status >= 400 ) {
          //throw error
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log("error"+err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now I can pass multiple receivers from different points when I dispatch the action from different sections by avoiding code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see much of your code from reducer, but seems to me you have too much logic around actions. Usually action is only intent to modify app state, so think twice about shape of your app state and just provide minimal information in actions that your reducer can compute the state. Also if you have to transform json and check status code for each request why not doing it in  api module, if you can't do anything about errors then you should not handle them, handle in api or reflect them in app state. App business logic always live in reducers. After this your action will look better and you will not worry about code repeat. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching for this I finally found something which I read in [redux-docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html) .

I used reusing reducer logic to handle repeated actions,state. This basically wraps a parent function around my reducer function to which I pass id as parameter and then create action types from my id dynamically.

Following code should really explain it clearly. Its from the docs itself.

```
function createCounterWithNamedType(counterName = '') {
    return function counter(state = 0, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case `INCREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state + 1;
            case `DECREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state - 1;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}
```